# python keyboard does not recognize keys

Tags: python, macos, keyboard, detect, keylogger

I am trying to detect the keys being pressed in python with "keyboard" but apparently it does not recognize the keys.
*(I use python 3.11.0 with macOs ventura 13.0)*

**my code**

```
import keyboard
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("a"):
        print("You pressed 'a'.")
        break
```

**and I get this error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/zzz.py", line 3, in <module>
    if keyboard.is_pressed("a"):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 417, in is_pressed
    steps = parse_hotkey(hotkey)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 344, in parse_hotkey
    scan_codes = key_to_scan_codes(hotkey)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 324, in key_to_scan_codes
    raise ValueError('Key {} is not mapped to any known key.'.format(repr(key)), e)
ValueError: ("Key 'a' is not mapped to any known key.", ValueError('Unrecognized character: a'))
```

Answer (score 1):

It can work well in Windows and Linux. But it is experimental on macos. There may be many bugs or no support. The author of the keyboard-module has declared, Details [boppreh/keyboard](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#features).

Comment: so what module could i use from macOs that works as keyboard?

Comment: [PyUserInput](https://pypi.org/project/PyUserInput/) is a good choice, but it is too old. It can be used in simple scenarios. It is recommended to use [pyobjc](https://pypi.org/project/pyobjc/) in complex scenarios, but it will increase the programming difficulty a little.